# Keyboard layout permanently modified/corrupted. Need help!

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

After restarting elementary many keystrokes return the wrong value, consistently across all keyboard layouts. I tried French, German, Japanese Layouts. 
Its also not due to my physical keyboard, which works fine when I boot into windows7.

- 'backspace' returns ']'
- 'apostrophe' ' returns 'backspace'
- '[' open brackets returns colon ':'

The onboard keyboard also seems to suggest that there are additional keys on my keyboard near enter and left shift for ESC and less than < . Is there a file I can edit or a way to reset all key assigments?

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue by reseting the entire system. Nothing else proved useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

OR

```
dconf reset -f /
```

Comment: Please add more information to answers like what you are suggesting and why you are suggesting. Please read, [How do I write a good answer?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)